# С# Visual Studio Перенос папки из проекта в debug/release

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Есть проект с исходным кодом, и папочка Extensions, (она не используется на этапе компиляции, а только после старта приложения) Как мне заставить VS2019 переносить эту папку в Debug/Release сборку проекта?
Вот так выглядит Папка проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Папочка пустая или в ней лежат нужные файлы?

Comment: Да, в папке хранятся файлы и подкаталоги

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У всех файлов в этой папке нужно выставить `Content` & `Copy always` или если файлы изменяются/редактируются во время написания проекта `Copy if newer`.